# Is it possible in Android to scroll a large table of data both up and down and side to side?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, datagrid, scrollview

Is it possible in Android to scroll a large table of data both up and down and side to side? I've got a table that is generated from a SQLite database. I would like to be able to browse it BOTH up and down and side to side. I've spent a lot of time with GridView, realizing that it ONLY accommodates up and down browsing. I've also done a quick implementation with TwoWayGridView which appears to do EITHER up and down, OR side to side browsing, but not both on the same table.
What is the accepted method of implementing two way browsing of a data table in Android?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Android not likely provide any default control to manage this kind of situation.You have to make your own custom gallery to swipe left-right. But this as per my experience it can only tackle light operation of your RAW file of gallery . you have to be a optimum.

> Gallery in the list view is not good idea since Gallery is deprecated
>   but it can at-least give you idea to use different horizontal adapter
>   like [tow-way-view](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view)

/**
Main class
**/

```
 public class Demo extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.demo);
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        List list = new List(Demo.this);
        listView.setAdapter(list);

    }
    }
```

/**
Custom adapter of vertical list , i have took list view but  you can use your Table layout
**/

```
public class List extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    public List(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return 50;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            GalleryAdepter adepter;
            adepter = new GalleryAdepter(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_list, null);
            BetterGallery betterGallery = (BetterGallery) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.betterGallery1);
            betterGallery.setAdapter(adepter);

        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

/**
Gallery adapter
**/

```
public class GalleryAdepter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    public GalleryAdepter(Context context) {
        this.context=context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return 50;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_gallery, null);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

/**
Custom Gallery 
**/

```
public class BetterGallery extends Gallery {
    private boolean scrollingHorizontally = false;

    public BetterGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public BetterGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public BetterGallery(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        return scrollingHorizontally;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        scrollingHorizontally = true;
        return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            scrollingHorizontally = false;
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2014 04 04 07:58 Possible solution added per response from user2009847...

main.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <HorizontalScrollView 
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent">



            <TableLayout 
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="No."
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                     <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="NAME"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="LOCATION"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
```

SampleTableActivity.java

```
package com.sample.table;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SampleTableActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    SQLiteDatabase database;
    private static String DBNAME = "sample.db";    
    private static String TABLE = "test";

    TableLayout tableLayout;
    TableRow row;
    TextView firstCol;
    TextView secondCol;
    TextView thirdCol;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tableLayout=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

        createDB();
        insertValues();
        displayDB();
    }


    private void displayDB() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        database=openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        if(database!=null)
        {
            Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+  TABLE, null);

            Integer index0=cursor.getColumnIndex("ID");
            Integer index1 = cursor.getColumnIndex("NAME"); 
            Integer index2 = cursor.getColumnIndex("LOCATION");
            if(cursor.getCount()>0)
            {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                do
                {
                    row=new TableRow(this);
                    row.setId(100);
                    row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  

                    /*Setting up the first coloumn parameters*/
                    firstCol=new TextView(this);
                    firstCol.setText(cursor.getString(index0));
                    firstCol.setTextSize(24);
                    firstCol.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    firstCol.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    row.addView(firstCol); //adding coloumn to row

                    /*Setting up the second coloumn parameters*/            
                    secondCol=new TextView(this);
                    secondCol.setText(cursor.getString(index1));
                    secondCol.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    secondCol.setTextSize(24);
                    secondCol.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    row.addView(secondCol); //adding coloumn to row

                    /*Setting up the third coloumn parameters*/
                    thirdCol=new TextView(this);
                    thirdCol.setText(cursor.getString(index2));
                    thirdCol.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                    thirdCol.setTextSize(24);
                    thirdCol.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    row.addView(thirdCol); //adding coloumn to row

                    /*Adding the row to the tablelayout*/
                    tableLayout.addView(row,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                }while(cursor.moveToNext());
                database.close();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "NOT AVAILABLE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }


    private void insertValues() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            database=openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(1,'African Elephant','INDIA')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(2,'French Bulldog','Brooklyn')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(3,'Giant Panda','Toronto')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(4,'African Elephant','Amundson-Scott Station')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(6,'French Bulldog','Charleston, WV')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(7,'Giant Panda','Miami')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(8,'African Elephant','Mexico City')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(9,'French Bulldog','Vladivostok, SI')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(10,'Great White Shark','Great Barrier Reef')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(11,'Giant Panda','Charleston, WV')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(12,'African Elephant','Brooklyn')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(13,'Giant Panda','Tokyo, JP')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(14,'French Bulldog','Brooklyn')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(15,'African Elephant','Tokyo, JP')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(16,'Giant Panda','Vladivostok, SI')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(17,'African Elephant','Brooklyn')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(18,'French Bulldog','Tokyo, JP')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(19,'Giant Panda','Brooklyn')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(20,'African Elephant','Vladivostok, SI')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(21,'French Bulldog','Tokyo, JP')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(22,'African Elephant','Brooklyn')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(23,'French Bulldog','Tokyo, JP')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(24,'African Elephant','Charleston, WV')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(25,'Giant Panda','Vladivostok, SI')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(26,'African Elephant','INDIA')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(27,'French Bulldog','Brooklyn')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(28,'Giant Panda','Toronto')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(29,'African Elephant','Amundson-Scott Station')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(30,'French Bulldog','Charleston, WV')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(31,'Giant Panda','Miami')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(32,'African Elephant','Mexico City')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(33,'French Bulldog','Vladivostok, SI')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(34,'Great White Shark','Great Barrier Reef')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(35,'Giant Panda','Charleston, WV')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(36,'African Elephant','Brooklyn')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(37,'Giant Panda','Tokyo, JP')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(38,'French Bulldog','Brooklyn')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(39,'African Elephant','Tokyo, JP')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(40,'Giant Panda','Vladivostok, SI')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(41,'African Elephant','Brooklyn')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(42,'French Bulldog','Tokyo, JP')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(43,'Giant Panda','Brooklyn')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(44,'African Elephant','Vladivostok, SI')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(45,'French Bulldog','Tokyo, JP')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(46,'African Elephant','Brooklyn')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(47,'French Bulldog','Tokyo, JP')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(48,'African Elephant','Charleston, WV')");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID,NAME, LOCATION) VALUES(49,'Giant Panda','Vladivostok, SI')");
            database.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;

    }


    private void createDB() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            database=openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF  NOT EXISTS "+ TABLE +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, NAME TEXT, LOCATION TEXT);");
            database.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Database Creation", "Error "+e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```